# ROS Odometry in Brushless motors without encoders

Tags: ros, brushless-motor

I have some experience building robots on ROS using brushed motors with encoders for a closed loop control. However after coming across brush less motors, they seem to have more torque to weight ratio and also less noise. The motors I am planning to use has three wires (Phase U, V and W) to control the motors and five wires (Hall A, B, C, Hall 5v and Hall Ground)  wires. Since there are no encoders, how can I get odometry output from this motor?

I have searched online. Few of them say it is possible to use hall sensors while others say we need to use the robot in open loop. Can someone plz shed some light on this issue?

If you there is a specific controller which can do the work using only hall sensors, plz confirm.

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

These motor controllers are aware of all the motor is doing, no? Don't they have possible output about the rpm and position? It may be the more feature-rich controller you want here. The signal coming into these controllers is commanding the rpm, no?